# ggplot2 - plotting two corresponding datasets with rows of varying sizes on the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to ggplot2 and I cannot find a satisfactory answer to my question.

I have two different corresponding data sets,CL and APD, each one containing a set of 50 arrays of varying size, say:

```
dput(head(CL, 10))
structure(list(V1 = c("1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,170,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,,,,,,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,,,,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,,,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,170,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,170,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,,,,,,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,,,,,,", 
"1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,,,"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(head(APD, 10))
structure(list(V1 = c("327.077176290064,321.375249530665,313.599632995433,308.726707234871,306.001312306735,303.066095022225,301.829212666914,300.556098201918,299.245158407373,297.89543983257,296.50590553305,295.075567539054,293.603418304663,292.08840872793,290.529487909855,288.925612812484,287.275699218356,285.578660678304,283.83339328787,282.038805643023,280.193799696108,278.297220217878,276.347933038864,274.344858907399,272.286856407784,270.172752386082,268.00145296509,265.771809388848,263.482727872719,261.133076773513,258.721792768636,256.247760974009,253.709994237276,251.107406195838,248.439012208639,245.703908573691,242.901147149326,240.029889167068,237.089386754615,234.078914803904,230.997893174885,227.845807545407,224.622377399768,221.32737139662,217.960837334382,214.523080815164,211.014699904824,207.436721635022,203.790779748489,200.079185695911,196.305366111669,192.474190717883,188.592733772294,184.671329254809,180.726330849298,176.785224673172,172.871897357513,168.933195929039,164.933972432768,,", 
"247.351567867118,247.319471282203,247.209870308118,247.078740000986,246.976278098718,246.837317517691,246.768805040355,246.691458236101,246.60413473585,246.505590987063,246.394415465094,246.269004476012,246.12762098231,245.968265820967,245.788744515215,245.586556331926,245.3589483264,245.102966688148,244.815140708449,244.491794476551,244.12879050516,243.721675926277,243.265476916378,242.754836814237,242.183989632549,241.546514830501,240.835808048146,240.044568159235,239.165236725376,238.189747934278,237.109709735086,235.916495044493,234.60128137674,233.155092289734,231.569161278711,229.834723702658,227.943516982358,225.887910144008,223.660940753992,221.257026252571,218.672055390198,215.903921360306,212.953208274873,209.824292184524,206.52630523689,203.075718021028,199.50013322673,195.84616444554,192.196966900728,188.713043699738,185.741733405446,184.135432777361,186.261417093275,198.914109741289,,,,,,,", 
"327.546296307457,323.573367712671,317.593982752044,313.577158771585,311.252528725737,308.691529102069,307.595825834528,306.457813096233,305.275787025218,304.048224322969,302.773707743687,301.450640343275,300.077550476463,298.652793156449,297.174842736821,295.642018014642,294.052724142297,292.405316067528,290.698079410022,288.929341565178,287.097441998869,285.200653739495,283.237273818412,281.205656077338,279.104069985335,276.930851034244,274.68438375465,272.363011634242,269.965190051601,267.48938737881,264.934104239358,262.297998291108,259.579725761866,256.778116929185,253.892117502375,250.920820312213,247.863534645339,244.719820460157,241.489496414457,238.17275953288,234.770288933841,231.283341529709,227.71392848502,224.065101411271,220.341339044021,216.549112412576,212.697854890102,208.8013645018,204.880559747397,200.967967736709,197.11630176037,193.415164544778,190.026186409651,187.262259992946,185.787093239225,187.194057666078,,,,,", 
"292.675044645301,291.026161277046,288.143861528221,285.987924394226,284.670468392882,283.164619551512,282.504104168014,281.807872722045,281.074169033041,280.301200618028,279.487072523456,278.629844185548,277.727531066303,276.778056358724,275.77928032375,274.729006991963,273.624999868746,272.464932219026,271.246437535985,269.967138630055,268.62453196632,267.216126386444,265.739360223012,264.191716838793,262.570540664634,260.873259986623,259.097255982043,257.239886762044,255.298626328587,253.27084459244,251.154048651615,248.945801588154,246.643730317217,244.245564792758,241.749184733505,239.152640832867,236.454178734428,233.652307840368,230.74585945692,227.73406534405,224.616619335264,221.393836776044,218.06681938696,214.637725438294,211.110091401959,207.489313999462,203.783600607544,200.005306566007,196.173338118236,192.317605853524,188.487377325887,184.768484604497,181.320647746327,178.464394830468,176.898548173074,178.244988580345,185.423811515913,,,,", 
"312.818792599764,308.748915594777,302.78292267341,298.845653204524,296.586216334059,294.110356052661,293.054939416179,291.960973152597,290.826909477337,289.651435496022,288.43327785259,287.171059652424,285.863402451355,284.508933574662,283.106200098179,281.653743061912,280.150128077119,278.593872363418,276.983407201124,275.317227472217,273.593788850109,271.811518296638,269.96884126162,268.064185098192,266.09597341093,264.062575993186,261.962446048425,259.794005578328,257.555643667581,255.245862259645,252.863144554058,250.405993740758,247.872952026807,245.262656374485,242.57380959631,239.805170559144,236.955594009328,234.024140760888,231.009932688199,227.912318318373,224.730875460036,221.465488501836,218.11638203249,214.684221384415,211.170271662728,207.576587002618,203.906234119569,200.163707495363,196.355597897345,192.491537578171,188.585773013375,184.660126133914,180.749077198022,176.909396550212,173.239399261108,169.920284717862,167.3072509052,166.046880852328,166.842131442703,,", 
"299.206980878464,296.664567084317,292.632345817021,289.817793663358,288.156717354806,286.302029570134,285.501348804194,284.665117268734,283.791897243492,282.880198338857,281.928535575604,280.935377260013,279.899164619133,278.81824518042,277.690990539147,276.515695319414,275.290642882951,274.014061124411,272.684161604509,271.299117073062,269.857052014748,268.356121933296,266.79442602794,265.169997328102,263.480937476314,261.725275594779,259.90107878266,258.006372742018,256.039200938947,253.997677001119,251.879831845369,249.683805630415,247.407748207451,245.049841902729,242.608428245545,240.081788781588,237.468394150444,234.76682515153,231.975798717767,229.094201583297,226.121129968332,223.055953138851,219.898396506182,216.648467785871,213.306841502512,209.874656131984,206.353984776633,202.748022791572,199.061507251555,195.301401735185,191.477995560876,187.606801828105,183.711555122995,179.829641779693,176.021781031497,172.391134424519,169.126909273202,166.618944985281,165.485251302789,,", 
"271.412612915788,271.131391789272,270.442982194293,269.789008625328,269.336779618151,268.77421800073,268.512695222068,268.227559937251,267.916827939107,267.578292432888,267.209630850936,266.808325155208,266.371682973634,265.89686867475,265.380781062058,264.820183934009,264.211627432402,263.55140400921,262.835742610231,262.060516681867,261.221495831032,260.314202069605,259.333990184774,258.276114553372,257.135562419359,255.907322119623,254.58614698034,253.166791725067,251.643973964305,250.012465836784,248.266938159175,246.402350835654,244.413711719276,242.296361940273,240.045903022875,237.658531693392,235.130866727143,232.460299716569,229.64516960355,226.685043217401,223.580865991126,220.335691287433,216.955287202333,213.449197390104,209.832698206243,206.130028282133,202.381020537518,198.654306791594,195.077255286285,191.907440226409,189.723079603757,189.975523620055,196.677798227148,219.620806105056,,,,,,,", 
"327.572780065149,322.614594643007,315.435630812752,310.7461401985,308.070256022511,305.150361550064,303.90899714978,302.624830013453,301.295975345523,299.921101444695,298.49890860414,297.028027001228,295.507129716563,293.934798743795,292.309691920376,290.63035487749,288.895416178883,287.103419311435,285.252923024025,283.342538666962,281.370819961801,279.336301997214,277.237586047581,275.073261381102,272.84189259036,270.542137357857,268.172642202123,265.732052897369,263.219120892045,260.632585696504,257.971303599324,255.234148591749,252.420128879569,249.528298509154,246.557869520083,243.508214799784,240.378805283203,237.169381306515,233.879929277987,230.510719362062,227.062411920791,223.53619656968,219.933868652951,216.258071245355,212.512644744037,208.703005013596,204.836984578566,200.926064259074,196.987312448112,193.047008749432,189.147083599924,185.356704921054,181.794461604411,178.669418060345,176.351435599791,175.439684407844,176.525832970156,178.486738724402,,,", 
"294.197381774123,293.490185055227,292.00380154684,290.737788620036,289.911541377902,288.924195314707,288.47781328152,287.999041980107,287.485721553832,286.935584057197,286.346271837721,285.715326528293,285.040057019747,284.317820547249,283.545699906382,282.720832676247,281.840073915475,280.900337423495,279.898300889769,278.830622187236,277.693910286813,276.48462124474,275.199216639447,273.834072093707,272.38561113994,270.850125989875,269.224087755012,267.503850481396,265.68589567927,263.766792836945,261.743239587708,259.61212412126,257.370422799746,255.0154660761,252.544787737571,249.956376236046,247.248536014966,244.420169786985,241.470673664573,238.400288242138,235.210096420921,231.902364062332,228.480809921064,224.951119375847,221.321813474915,217.605314622858,213.820339616812,209.99583162597,206.178457683648,202.447922791827,198.949845625743,195.97184788345,194.135719296741,194.928101836179,202.185682379486,,,,,,", 
"278.739019258855,276.725157359385,273.306806325205,270.804610176683,269.29275291061,267.578094042589,266.829999334928,266.043951596763,265.218255088055,264.351036140359,263.44057090097,262.484964537445,261.482239468334,260.43043164418,259.327538083493,258.171462963947,256.960067534814,255.691235898772,254.362680618959,252.972234829916,251.517590164625,249.996453603727,248.406497356101,246.745360166322,245.010808496984,243.200399704461,241.311831504424,239.342773301557,237.291038175944,235.154265179068,232.930391392096,230.617266142337,228.212878901724,225.715345062636,223.122916303555,220.434014335025,217.647269173877,214.761609117442,211.776183442255,208.690552473048,205.504742652881,202.219357818187,198.835734918225,195.356188879249,191.784315052272,188.125379003332,184.387291431741,180.581636753991,176.725917903931,172.847277102796,168.989730429227,165.228018493107,161.698019571505,158.664581766773,156.687572032148,157.033541330501,162.31572947346,171.471095185618,,,"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to plot them in the same plot as APD_1 vs. CL_1, APD_2 vs. CL_2,...,APD_50 vs. CL_50 each one as a line.

[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKi29.jpg)

Can you please help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you please `dput(BP)` and post the result? Thanks

Comment: Does adding `stat = "summary"` to `geom_line` work for you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the code shared, you should change the names in mapping = aes().
It should be mapping = aes(CLlong, APlong).
Maybe that is the only error. Else it looks fine.

Comment: @Brigadeiro Hi. By doing that, I just get a line.

Comment: @TarJae. HI. I will post the result but the output is a huge file. The one I posted was edited to make it easier.

Comment: Just type `dput(head(BP))` in  your console. copy and add it to your question.

Comment: @TarJae. I have done that, but it says the the number of character should be 30000 and I have more than twice that.

Comment: @kashj. Thank you. I changed that, but that was really not the problem. I have edited the example from what I have on my computer to make it simpler.

Comment: @Community. I accept that even making the question is difficult for me. I added a graph of the way it should look like (from Matlab).

Comment: Maybe `dput(head(BP, 50))` would be better to generate representative data. But the `dput()` output does not seem to match the structure shown in the question. Could you explain the difference, thanks.

Comment: @Peter. Hi, Peter. I already added what you asked me (dput(head(BP, 50))), but you are right in the sense that I have at least been able to plot the two long vectors using geom_point. What I really have is what appears on top (I just wrote it down in an easier way to read). To explain myself better, it is like if I had two matrices X and Y of the same size and I wanted to plot the first row of X against the first row of Y and that for all rows. But what I have are not matrices because the length of each row is different. Maybe my solution is confusing the question. Thank you.

Comment: What do you have? Is it lots of vectors which can be paired or two separate lists with  vector elements (paired by position).  Without a realistic data it's going to be difficult to help. I'm afraid the larger `dput()` does not really help as it does not include pairs of vectors.

Comment: @Peter. Okay, Peter. I erased my solution and gave the data that I actually have, but only 10 and not 50 because it is too big. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that your preparation is a bit wrong.

```
df1 = structure(list(V1 = c("1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,170,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,,,,,,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,,,,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,,,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,170,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,170,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,,,,,,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,,,,,,", 
                      "1000,900,800,750,725,700,690,680,670,660,650,640,630,620,610,600,590,580,570,560,550,540,530,520,510,500,490,480,470,460,450,440,430,420,410,400,390,380,370,360,350,340,330,320,310,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,210,200,190,180,,,"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
df2 = structure(list(V1 = c("327.077176290064,321.375249530665,313.599632995433,308.726707234871,306.001312306735,303.066095022225,301.829212666914,300.556098201918,299.245158407373,297.89543983257,296.50590553305,295.075567539054,293.603418304663,292.08840872793,290.529487909855,288.925612812484,287.275699218356,285.578660678304,283.83339328787,282.038805643023,280.193799696108,278.297220217878,276.347933038864,274.344858907399,272.286856407784,270.172752386082,268.00145296509,265.771809388848,263.482727872719,261.133076773513,258.721792768636,256.247760974009,253.709994237276,251.107406195838,248.439012208639,245.703908573691,242.901147149326,240.029889167068,237.089386754615,234.078914803904,230.997893174885,227.845807545407,224.622377399768,221.32737139662,217.960837334382,214.523080815164,211.014699904824,207.436721635022,203.790779748489,200.079185695911,196.305366111669,192.474190717883,188.592733772294,184.671329254809,180.726330849298,176.785224673172,172.871897357513,168.933195929039,164.933972432768,,", 
                      "247.351567867118,247.319471282203,247.209870308118,247.078740000986,246.976278098718,246.837317517691,246.768805040355,246.691458236101,246.60413473585,246.505590987063,246.394415465094,246.269004476012,246.12762098231,245.968265820967,245.788744515215,245.586556331926,245.3589483264,245.102966688148,244.815140708449,244.491794476551,244.12879050516,243.721675926277,243.265476916378,242.754836814237,242.183989632549,241.546514830501,240.835808048146,240.044568159235,239.165236725376,238.189747934278,237.109709735086,235.916495044493,234.60128137674,233.155092289734,231.569161278711,229.834723702658,227.943516982358,225.887910144008,223.660940753992,221.257026252571,218.672055390198,215.903921360306,212.953208274873,209.824292184524,206.52630523689,203.075718021028,199.50013322673,195.84616444554,192.196966900728,188.713043699738,185.741733405446,184.135432777361,186.261417093275,198.914109741289,,,,,,,", 
                      "327.546296307457,323.573367712671,317.593982752044,313.577158771585,311.252528725737,308.691529102069,307.595825834528,306.457813096233,305.275787025218,304.048224322969,302.773707743687,301.450640343275,300.077550476463,298.652793156449,297.174842736821,295.642018014642,294.052724142297,292.405316067528,290.698079410022,288.929341565178,287.097441998869,285.200653739495,283.237273818412,281.205656077338,279.104069985335,276.930851034244,274.68438375465,272.363011634242,269.965190051601,267.48938737881,264.934104239358,262.297998291108,259.579725761866,256.778116929185,253.892117502375,250.920820312213,247.863534645339,244.719820460157,241.489496414457,238.17275953288,234.770288933841,231.283341529709,227.71392848502,224.065101411271,220.341339044021,216.549112412576,212.697854890102,208.8013645018,204.880559747397,200.967967736709,197.11630176037,193.415164544778,190.026186409651,187.262259992946,185.787093239225,187.194057666078,,,,,", 
                      "292.675044645301,291.026161277046,288.143861528221,285.987924394226,284.670468392882,283.164619551512,282.504104168014,281.807872722045,281.074169033041,280.301200618028,279.487072523456,278.629844185548,277.727531066303,276.778056358724,275.77928032375,274.729006991963,273.624999868746,272.464932219026,271.246437535985,269.967138630055,268.62453196632,267.216126386444,265.739360223012,264.191716838793,262.570540664634,260.873259986623,259.097255982043,257.239886762044,255.298626328587,253.27084459244,251.154048651615,248.945801588154,246.643730317217,244.245564792758,241.749184733505,239.152640832867,236.454178734428,233.652307840368,230.74585945692,227.73406534405,224.616619335264,221.393836776044,218.06681938696,214.637725438294,211.110091401959,207.489313999462,203.783600607544,200.005306566007,196.173338118236,192.317605853524,188.487377325887,184.768484604497,181.320647746327,178.464394830468,176.898548173074,178.244988580345,185.423811515913,,,,", 
                      "312.818792599764,308.748915594777,302.78292267341,298.845653204524,296.586216334059,294.110356052661,293.054939416179,291.960973152597,290.826909477337,289.651435496022,288.43327785259,287.171059652424,285.863402451355,284.508933574662,283.106200098179,281.653743061912,280.150128077119,278.593872363418,276.983407201124,275.317227472217,273.593788850109,271.811518296638,269.96884126162,268.064185098192,266.09597341093,264.062575993186,261.962446048425,259.794005578328,257.555643667581,255.245862259645,252.863144554058,250.405993740758,247.872952026807,245.262656374485,242.57380959631,239.805170559144,236.955594009328,234.024140760888,231.009932688199,227.912318318373,224.730875460036,221.465488501836,218.11638203249,214.684221384415,211.170271662728,207.576587002618,203.906234119569,200.163707495363,196.355597897345,192.491537578171,188.585773013375,184.660126133914,180.749077198022,176.909396550212,173.239399261108,169.920284717862,167.3072509052,166.046880852328,166.842131442703,,", 
                      "299.206980878464,296.664567084317,292.632345817021,289.817793663358,288.156717354806,286.302029570134,285.501348804194,284.665117268734,283.791897243492,282.880198338857,281.928535575604,280.935377260013,279.899164619133,278.81824518042,277.690990539147,276.515695319414,275.290642882951,274.014061124411,272.684161604509,271.299117073062,269.857052014748,268.356121933296,266.79442602794,265.169997328102,263.480937476314,261.725275594779,259.90107878266,258.006372742018,256.039200938947,253.997677001119,251.879831845369,249.683805630415,247.407748207451,245.049841902729,242.608428245545,240.081788781588,237.468394150444,234.76682515153,231.975798717767,229.094201583297,226.121129968332,223.055953138851,219.898396506182,216.648467785871,213.306841502512,209.874656131984,206.353984776633,202.748022791572,199.061507251555,195.301401735185,191.477995560876,187.606801828105,183.711555122995,179.829641779693,176.021781031497,172.391134424519,169.126909273202,166.618944985281,165.485251302789,,", 
                      "271.412612915788,271.131391789272,270.442982194293,269.789008625328,269.336779618151,268.77421800073,268.512695222068,268.227559937251,267.916827939107,267.578292432888,267.209630850936,266.808325155208,266.371682973634,265.89686867475,265.380781062058,264.820183934009,264.211627432402,263.55140400921,262.835742610231,262.060516681867,261.221495831032,260.314202069605,259.333990184774,258.276114553372,257.135562419359,255.907322119623,254.58614698034,253.166791725067,251.643973964305,250.012465836784,248.266938159175,246.402350835654,244.413711719276,242.296361940273,240.045903022875,237.658531693392,235.130866727143,232.460299716569,229.64516960355,226.685043217401,223.580865991126,220.335691287433,216.955287202333,213.449197390104,209.832698206243,206.130028282133,202.381020537518,198.654306791594,195.077255286285,191.907440226409,189.723079603757,189.975523620055,196.677798227148,219.620806105056,,,,,,,", 
                      "327.572780065149,322.614594643007,315.435630812752,310.7461401985,308.070256022511,305.150361550064,303.90899714978,302.624830013453,301.295975345523,299.921101444695,298.49890860414,297.028027001228,295.507129716563,293.934798743795,292.309691920376,290.63035487749,288.895416178883,287.103419311435,285.252923024025,283.342538666962,281.370819961801,279.336301997214,277.237586047581,275.073261381102,272.84189259036,270.542137357857,268.172642202123,265.732052897369,263.219120892045,260.632585696504,257.971303599324,255.234148591749,252.420128879569,249.528298509154,246.557869520083,243.508214799784,240.378805283203,237.169381306515,233.879929277987,230.510719362062,227.062411920791,223.53619656968,219.933868652951,216.258071245355,212.512644744037,208.703005013596,204.836984578566,200.926064259074,196.987312448112,193.047008749432,189.147083599924,185.356704921054,181.794461604411,178.669418060345,176.351435599791,175.439684407844,176.525832970156,178.486738724402,,,", 
                      "294.197381774123,293.490185055227,292.00380154684,290.737788620036,289.911541377902,288.924195314707,288.47781328152,287.999041980107,287.485721553832,286.935584057197,286.346271837721,285.715326528293,285.040057019747,284.317820547249,283.545699906382,282.720832676247,281.840073915475,280.900337423495,279.898300889769,278.830622187236,277.693910286813,276.48462124474,275.199216639447,273.834072093707,272.38561113994,270.850125989875,269.224087755012,267.503850481396,265.68589567927,263.766792836945,261.743239587708,259.61212412126,257.370422799746,255.0154660761,252.544787737571,249.956376236046,247.248536014966,244.420169786985,241.470673664573,238.400288242138,235.210096420921,231.902364062332,228.480809921064,224.951119375847,221.321813474915,217.605314622858,213.820339616812,209.99583162597,206.178457683648,202.447922791827,198.949845625743,195.97184788345,194.135719296741,194.928101836179,202.185682379486,,,,,,", 
                      "278.739019258855,276.725157359385,273.306806325205,270.804610176683,269.29275291061,267.578094042589,266.829999334928,266.043951596763,265.218255088055,264.351036140359,263.44057090097,262.484964537445,261.482239468334,260.43043164418,259.327538083493,258.171462963947,256.960067534814,255.691235898772,254.362680618959,252.972234829916,251.517590164625,249.996453603727,248.406497356101,246.745360166322,245.010808496984,243.200399704461,241.311831504424,239.342773301557,237.291038175944,235.154265179068,232.930391392096,230.617266142337,228.212878901724,225.715345062636,223.122916303555,220.434014335025,217.647269173877,214.761609117442,211.776183442255,208.690552473048,205.504742652881,202.219357818187,198.835734918225,195.356188879249,191.784315052272,188.125379003332,184.387291431741,180.581636753991,176.725917903931,172.847277102796,168.989730429227,165.228018493107,161.698019571505,158.664581766773,156.687572032148,157.033541330501,162.31572947346,171.471095185618,,,"
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also note that your APD and CL vectors have different lengths.
They must first be broken down into individual variables

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 = df1 %>% separate(V1, into = paste0("APD_",1:60), sep=",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("APD_"), names_to = "APD", values_to = "APDval") %>% 
  mutate(xy = str_extract(APD, "\\d+") %>% fct_inorder())
df_2 = df2 %>% separate(V1, into = paste0("CL_",1:60), sep=",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("CL_"), names_to = "CL", values_to = "CLval") %>% 
  mutate(xy = str_extract(CL, "\\d+") %>% fct_inorder())
```

output

```
# A tibble: 600 x 3
   APD    APDval xy   
   <chr>   <int> <fct>
 1 APD_1    1000 1    
 2 APD_2     900 2    
 3 APD_3     800 3    
 4 APD_4     750 4    
 5 APD_5     725 5    
 6 APD_6     700 6    
 7 APD_7     690 7    
 8 APD_8     680 8    
 9 APD_9     670 9    
10 APD_10    660 10   
# ... with 590 more rows

> df_2
# A tibble: 600 x 3
   CL    CLval xy   
   <chr> <dbl> <fct>
 1 CL_1   327. 1    
 2 CL_2   321. 2    
 3 CL_3   314. 3    
 4 CL_4   309. 4    
 5 CL_5   306. 5    
 6 CL_6   303. 6    
 7 CL_7   302. 7    
 8 CL_8   301. 8    
 9 CL_9   299. 9    
10 CL_10  298. 10   
# ... with 590 more rows
```

Then we have to put it all together. For this, I gave an `xy` column that will allow for such joining.

```
df = df_1 %>% left_join(df_2, by="xy")
```

output

```
# A tibble: 6,000 x 5
   APD   APDval xy    CL    CLval
   <chr>  <int> <fct> <chr> <dbl>
 1 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   327.
 2 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   247.
 3 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   328.
 4 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   293.
 5 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   313.
 6 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   299.
 7 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   271.
 8 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   328.
 9 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   294.
10 APD_1   1000 1     CL_1   279.
# ... with 5,990 more rows
```

Now making a plot is a breeze

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(CLval, APDval, col=xy)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Now I understand. You made it a bit confusing in the description. If you expect what's below, you'll need to convert your data to the appropriate format once again.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 = df1 %>% mutate(cycle = paste("Cycle",1:10) %>% fct_inorder()) %>% 
  separate(V1, into = paste0("APD_",1:60), sep=",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("APD_"), names_to = "APD", values_to = "APDval") %>% 
  mutate(cycle.xy = paste(cycle, str_extract(APD, "\\d+")) %>% fct_inorder())
df_2 = df2 %>% mutate(cycle = paste("Cycle",1:10) %>% fct_inorder()) %>%
  separate(V1, into = paste0("CL_",1:60), sep=",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("CL_"), names_to = "CL", values_to = "CLval") %>% 
  mutate(cycle.xy = paste(cycle, str_extract(CL, "\\d+")) %>% fct_inorder())



df = df_1 %>% left_join(df_2, by="cycle.xy") %>% mutate(Cycle = cycle.x) %>% 
  select(APDval, CLval, Cycle)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 600 x 3
   APDval CLval Cycle  
    <int> <dbl> <fct>  
 1   1000  327. Cycle 1
 2    900  321. Cycle 1
 3    800  314. Cycle 1
 4    750  309. Cycle 1
 5    725  306. Cycle 1
 6    700  303. Cycle 1
 7    690  302. Cycle 1
 8    680  301. Cycle 1
 9    670  299. Cycle 1
10    660  298. Cycle 1
# ... with 590 more rows
```

Creating a plot is still as easy as before.

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(APDval, CLval, col=Cycle)) +
  geom_line()+
  xlab("Cycle length (ms)")+
  ylab("Action potental duration (ms)")
```

[image]

If the default colors do not suit you, you can always change it

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(APDval, CLval, col=Cycle)) +
  geom_line()+
  xlab("Cycle length (ms)")+
  ylab("Action potental duration (ms)") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

[image]

And if you do not need to distinguish between cycles and you want everything in blue, you can always do this:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(APDval, CLval, group=Cycle)) +
  geom_line(col="blue")+
  xlab("Cycle length (ms)")+
  ylab("Action potental duration (ms)")
```

[image]

Be sure to check out http://www.sthda.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was trying to understand what you did, but I started using ggplot2 this week and it is not easy for me. The truth is that each plot needs to be a function of CL. The way the graph is plotted, all same APD values are connected with a horizontal line and that is not what I need. It needs to be the first row of df1 vs first row of df2 and like that consecutively, like the plot I added from Matlab. Thank you again.

Comment: Alejandro, I must admit that I felt just as confused when I wanted to create my first `ggplot` storyline. However, when I got to know the possibilities of this package, I love what I can do with it. This is fantastic! I encourage you to read carefully all the articles in the Visualizations section that you can find at http://www.sthda.com/

Comment: Marek, thank you very much for your help and suggestions. That is exactly what I was looking for. May you have a nice day.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Remember, however, that on Stack Overflow, you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.

Comment: @Mark. I clicked the arrow up, but it says that I need to have a reputation of 15; anyway, they say my answer has been recorded anyway. I have a last question: what do I have just one color without the legends? I added one color but it still give me all those colors.

Comment: You really need at least 15 reputation points to vote for an answer (up arrow). However, you can always accept the answer by pressing the select button below the arrows. Read it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers